# Quickly switch to layout editor in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there a commmand or shortcut for quickly jump from code editor to graphical layout editor?
For example I am editing MyActivity.java and it's layout is in activity_layout.xml.

In layout editor there is a button for jumping to code, I just need reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First press Ctrl+F12, then press home to jump to main Class name, for example MyActivity, then press enter and now select Navigate | Related File... ( or press Ctrl+Alt+Home in Windows or CMD+ALT+Home on mac)